# How To Integrate PayPal Donate Button In Phonegap, JQuery Mobile With Dreamweaver

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am trying to integrate paypal donate button in my phonegap-jquery mobile application, but the button doesn't appear and not working. is there any way to display the button or any easy way to display the paypal inside my app?

Here is The App Code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="file:///C|/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5/Configuration/Third Party Source Code/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="file:///C|/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5/Configuration/Third Party Source Code/jquery-mobile/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file:///C|/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5/Configuration/Third Party Source Code/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- This reference to phonegap.js will allow for code hints as long as the current site has been configured as a mobile application. 
     To configure the site as a mobile application, go to Site -> Mobile Applications -> Configure Application Framework... -->
<script src="/phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#page2">Page Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Page Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Page Four</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

And Here is the Button Code -

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

when i add the button code in any page, a blank button will appear and don't show anything! Any Idea?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

For one your script links won't work when compiled by Phonegap

```
<script src="file:///C|/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5/Configuration/Third Party Source Code/jquery-mobile/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That path is only available to your local computer. You would need to use a relative path, like jquery-mobile/jquery-1.5.min.js as the script src

The button looks like it's pulling it's images from the Internet, have you enabled access to that domain in Phonegap?
Another option is to download the image and use a relative link to it rather then the http:// link

If you want to use the first option, take a look at the guide on Whitelist domains

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Answer (score 0):

HI You will have use phonegap paypal plugin library depending on the phone you are targeting. here is the git repo and instructions you will need
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/PayPalPlugin